# Unable to simultaneously satisfy a single constraint

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have an odd case - I'll try to isolate, but figured I'd throw a question up in the meantime. I have a UILabel that has a height constraint. When I try to set the height to 0, I get this (not super helpful) error:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b9b5d90 V:[UILabel:0x7b9c6cf0(0)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b9b5d90 V:[UILabel:0x7b9c6cf0(0)]>

Break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The confusing part for me is that the error says "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints", but only shows a single constraint. Also it recovers by breaking that single constraint.

How can a constraint conflict with itself?

Comment: How do you set this constraint?

Comment: I have an `IBOutlet` pointing to a constraint created in IB, and I set the `constant` property on the IBOutlet property.

Comment: I've the same issue with a width constraint on a UIView loaded from a nib, constraint is created in code. Have you figured out anything about it since posting?

Comment: I don't believe I found the answer to this, I'd have to try to repro - off the top of my head, I know that UILabel does it's own layout stuff, so perhaps it could be related to the automatic adjustment based on text?